# How do I pass a page scoped object to a custom JSP tag using Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, ognl

I am using Struts 2 and I need to pass a page scoped variable to a custom JSP tag.

If I use OGNL syntax `%{#option}` I get the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6338: Cannot convert "%{#option}" for the attribute option of the bean com.leaseplanis.iq.model.bo.options.OptionDetail
```

Where as if I use EL syntax `${option}` I the object is `null`.

My custom tag is located at */WEB-INF/tags/option_price_textfield.tag* in my web application:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ tag body-content="empty"%>
<%@ attribute name="option" type="com.leaseplanis.iq.model.bo.options.OptionDetail" required="true" rtexprvalue="true"%>

<s:textfield
    id="%{optionId(#option, 'price')}"
    name="%{optionField(#option, 'price')}"
    value="%{optionGrossPrice(#option).getString()}"
    cssClass="input price"
    size="8"
    maxlength="11"
    onchange="%{optionPriceUpdate(#option)}" />
```

The custom tag is used in the following JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="iq" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
.
.
<s:iterator var="option" value="variousOptionList">
    .
    .
    <s:if test="viewConfigService.displayPriceColumn()">
        <td class="price">
            <s:if test="isPriceEditable(#option)">
                <iq:option_price_textfield option="%{#option}"/>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
                <s:property value="optionGrossPrice(#option).getString()"/>
            </s:else>
            <s:property default="&nbsp;" escape="false" value="#option.optionCur"/>
        </td>
    </s:if>
    .
    .
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: check this quite similar to what you asking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521375/passing-a-value-to-a-custom-tag  You need to parse the object explicitly as an OGNL expression

Comment: @umesh - Do you know how I could evaluate the expression in my .tag file? The solution to that other question would definitely work if I had coded my tags in Java.

Comment: how you have implemented that tag library? i am not very sure about converting it there,but with details might be some one else can help you .

Comment: @umesh - The approach described in the question you referenced does indeed work. However, I'm having to write over 5 times as much Java code compared to JSP.

Comment: Thing is in Struts2 OGNL and value-stack has been integrated in a very good way and what was you trying to do is something out of box so a bit of extra code is always there :),Good thing is it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OGNL allows access to scoped attributes like `option` via `#attr`. Change the `option` accesses to use that and you should be all set:

```
<s:textfield
    id="%{optionId(#attr.option, 'price')}"
    name="%{optionField(#attr.option, 'price')}"
    value="%{optionGrossPrice(#attr.option).getString()}"
    cssClass="input price"
    size="8"
    maxlength="11"
    onchange="%{optionPriceUpdate(#attr.option)}" />
```